# Уместить String в клетку TableView Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Проблема такова, что в tableVeiw передается очень длинная строка. Она не умещается по длине на экране сотового телефона ( и соответственно не читабельна).

Можно как-нибудь сделать, что бы IOs увеличивал автоматически клетку по высоте что бы строка умещалась послностью?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно указать, что высота ячеек не фиксирована:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Ну и указать высоту ячеек в среднем:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
```

Comment: В функуии viewDidLoad писал, viewDidAppear писал, numberOfRowsInSection писал. По брекпоинтоам срабатывает, но изменений нет!  что-то дела не так?

Comment: Вроде сделал! Но строка так и не переноситься на пустое место вниз. Как быть?

Comment: @IgorZexyy для начала, какая разметка в ячейке? Установили у UILabel number of rows равное 0?

Comment: Разметка в ячейке? Я использую две функции numberOfRowsInSection и cellForRowAt. У меня идет вызов данных из Firebase и я пишу длинную строку с ними и передаю их в массив array, который и используется для отображения tableView. Текст в таблицу я передаю через cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

Comment: Я самоучка. Участь по Ютубу! Там таблицы так учат делать. Про разметку ячейки я могу ничего просто не знать...

Comment: @IgorZexyy в cellForRow пропишите cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: Спасибо, кэп! Работает! Давайте обменяемся контактам?

Comment: А как текст центрировать? У меня выравнивание по правой стороне в клетке...

Comment: @IgorZexyy cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center по центру, .left - лево, .right - право, .justified - по ширине

Comment: Спасибо! Все сделал! А вот смотри, если мне например надо выделить клетку и начать ее редактирование мне надо использовать функцию didSelectRowAt?